# How to implement smart contract to add eth address record to refer the specific ENS subdomain name in solidity

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity

I have wrote the smart contract for creating ENS subdomain name. I need to pass the reference ETH address record for that created subdomain name.[image: This is the sample subdomain name that I was created. I need to add the ETH address inside the records using the smart contract without add manually.]

```
    pragma solidity >=0.8.4;

import "./ENS.sol";

contract EnsSubdomain {
    ENS public immutable ens;
    bytes32 public immutable rootNode;

    constructor(ENS ensAddr, bytes32 node) {
        ens = ensAddr;
        rootNode = node;
    }

    function createSubdomain(
        bytes32 label,
        address owner,
        address resolver,
        uint64 ttl
    ) public {
        ens.setSubnodeRecord(rootNode, label, owner, resolver, ttl);
    }
}
```

Hereby I have attached the codebase that I have implemented in solidity to create the subdomain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to add the Eth address to the record for referring the specific subdomain name. I've used the public contract address  "0xf6305c19e814d2a75429Fd637d01F7ee0E77d615" along with the ABI file provided for this contract address.

And implemented the method named "setAddr" that was published under the same ABI and the Contract address.

For more reference, Can visit the provided link.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf6305c19e814d2a75429Fd637d01F7ee0E77d615#code